# Changing Chartjs Horizontal Scrollling Direction

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I would like to change the direction of scrolling on a horizontal scrollable bar chart in such way scrolling start from **right** to **left** (*RTL*). I'm not sure if it is supported or not. in case, it is not, then is there a way to **programmatically** scroll to the **far right** of the chart upon loading to achieve the desired outcome.

```js
const chartsoptions = {
 type: 'bar',
 data: {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",],
  datasets: [{
   label: 'OFF',
   data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   backgroundColor:   [ 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.4)', ],
   borderColor:   [ 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',  ],
   borderWidth: 1
  },{
   label: 'On',
   data: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
   backgroundColor:  [ 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)', ],
   borderColor:   ['rgb(75, 192, 192)',   ],
   borderWidth: 1
  }]
 },
 options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
       display: true,
       labels: {
        font: {
         size: 20,
         weight: "bold",
        },
       }
    },
    datalabels: {
     anchor: 'center', 
     clamp: true, 
     display: true, 
     textAlign: 'center', 
     borderRadius: 3, 
     color: "black", 
     clip: true,
     font: {
      size: 20,
      weight: "bold",
     },

   },  
   zoom: {
    zoom: {   wheel: { enabled: false, },  mode: 'x', },
    pan: {   enabled: true,  mode: 'x', },
    limits: { x: { minRange: 3 }, },
   }
  },
  scales: {
   x: { ticks: { font: { size: 20, weight: "bold" }, } },
   y: { ticks: { font: { size: 20, weight: "bold" }, } },
  }
 }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('dailyonoff').getContext('2d');
document.getElementById('dailyonoff').style.backgroundColor = "white"; 
const chart = new Chart(ctx, chartsoptions);

setTimeout(() => {
  chart.zoom(2);
  chart.pan({
    x: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  }, undefined, 'default');
}, 10)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js" integrity="sha256-+8RZJua0aEWg+QVVKg4LEzEEm/8RFez5Tb4JBNiV5xA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.1.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.js"></script>   

 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="dailyonoff"   class="onoff" width="300" height="200" ></canvas>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to navigate (pan) to the end of the graph. just replace:

```
MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
```

with:

```
MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
```